# Custom lightning component does not filter records by parent record ID

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I created a custom lightning component to display on contact page. It does not filter to match the contact record id, instead it show all records.
I checked the spelling of all parameters etc.

my controller

```
({
    assTrainees: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAssActiveITFTrainees");
        action.setParams({"contactId": component.get("v.recordId")}); 
        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            component.set("v.traineerows", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex Controller:

```
global class Ass_CP_ActiveTraineeAuraController {

    @AuraEnabled
    //ITF trainee list
    global static List<Ass_ActiveTraineesQueryResults> getAssActiveITFTrainees(id contactId){


        List<AggregateResult> agrResults = [Select
                                            Assessor__c assessorId,
                                            Training_Plan__r.TraineeRef__c traineeId, 
                                            Training_Plan__r.TraineeRef__r.Name trainee, 
                                            Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__r.Progress_Updated__c progress,
                                            Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__r.Programme__c qual, 
                                            Training_Plan__r.Trainee_Workplace__r.Name company,
                                            Training_Plan__r.Participation_Start_Date__c startdate,
                                            Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__r.Expected_Completion__c enddate,  
                                            Training_Plan__r.TraineeRef__r.LastName lname
                                            FROM Assessment_Schedule__c 
                                            where 
                                            Assessor__c =:contactId AND
                                            (Tec_Status__c = 'Active' OR Tec_Status__c = 'On Hold' OR Non_TEC_Status__c = 'Active' 
                                             OR Non_TEC_Status__c = 'On Hold') AND Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__r.Progress__c < 100 
                                            And Complete__c=NULL
                                            AND (Funding_Source__c = 'IT - Industry Training'OR Funding_Source__c = 'UF - Un-funded') 
                                            group by
                                            Assessor__c,
                                            Training_Plan__r.TraineeRef__c, 
                                            Training_Plan__r.TraineeRef__r.Name, 
                                            Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__r.Progress_updated__c,
                                            Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__r.Programme__c, 
                                            Training_Plan__r.Trainee_Workplace__r.Name,
                                            Training_Plan__r.Participation_Start_Date__c,
                                            Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__r.Expected_Completion__c,  
                                            Training_Plan__r.TraineeRef__r.LastName 
                                            ORDER by Training_Plan__r.TraineeRef__r.LastName];


        List<Ass_ActiveTraineesQueryResults> aqResults = new List<Ass_ActiveTraineesQueryResults>(); 

        for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults){
            aqResults.add(new Ass_ActiveTraineesQueryResults(ar));  
        }
        return aqResults;
    }
}

global class Ass_ActiveTraineesQueryResults {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Assessor {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String TraineeId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String TraineeName {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Progress {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Workplace {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Qualification {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Date StartDate {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Date ExpectedEndDate {get; set;}
    //constructor
    global Ass_ActiveTraineesQueryResults(AggregateResult ar){
        Assessor = (String)ar.get('assessorId');
        TraineeId = (String)ar.get('traineeId');
        TraineeName = (String)ar.get('trainee');
        Progress = (String)ar.get('progress');
        Workplace = (String)ar.get('company');
        Qualification = (String)ar.get('qual');
        StartDate = (Date)ar.get('startdate');
        ExpectedEndDate = (Date)ar.get('enddate');

    }
}
```

part of my component:

```
 <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:attribute name="traineerows" type="Ass_ActiveTraineesQueryResults[]"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="id" />
```

Comment: You will need to provide more code here for anyone to be able to help you. What does your apex controller method do? How is your component written? All these details will be required.

Comment: I have included apex controller with the constructor and part of my component. This fetch all records.

Comment: Did you remember to use force:hasRecordId?

Comment: Yes, on the component under implements

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to fix it by setting parameter as contactId instead of "contactId" in helper.jr